# JQuery attempt to change window.location incorrectly truncating query parameters

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery

I'm experimenting with JQuery for fun and I've run into a bit of a brick wall. I'm attempting to write a login page and my thought was to have a form on a jsp where a user would enter a login id and password and click a submit button. This then gets caught by a JQuery method that then makes an AJAX call to the back-end. The "success" method should then set the window object's location to a new URL indicated by the value returned from the Ajax call. FYI: I'm a back-end guy and I have that portion covered. My problem is that although I call the back-end and get the data I require. I then attempt to set a new window location with a URL that contains a single query parameter (to allow the app to know who the user is), which almost works as I get to the base URL but with no query parameters (though there is a '?' on the end of the base URL)

Here's my JQuery code:

```
    </script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        submit( function() {
          var id = $("#login_id").val();
          var pwd = $("#password").val();
          var uri = "`http://localhost:8080/SW_Server/rest/admin/login`";
          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: uri,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
              var session = data.session;
              newLoc = data.redirect+"?"+data.session
              // Prevent the form's default submission.
              preventDefault();
              // Prevent event from bubbling up DOM tree, prohibiting delegation
              event.stopPropagation();
              window.location.replace(encodeURIComponent(newLoc));
            },
          error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("textStatus: "+textStatus+"\nerror: "+errorThrown);
            // Prevent the form's default submission.
            event.preventDefault();
            // Prevent event from bubbling up DOM tree, prohibiting delegation
            event.stopPropagation();          
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

When I execute this, my back end currently returns data.redirect=`http://localhost:8080/test.jsp` and data.session=session_id=3, which I see in an alert (hooray for me), but then when window.location.replace(newLoc) is called it goes to `http://localhost:8080/test.jsp?` with no query parameter. I've been banging my head all day. What can I do to get the query param correctly picked up by the new page?

Regards,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the value to `location` instead

```
window.location = data.redirect;
```

Comment: Ya, that didn't work either. I reflected that in an edit to my original post. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

did you try some of this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#loginForm").submit( function(event) {
          var id = $("#login_id").val();
          var pwd = $("#password").val();
          var uri = "http://localhost:8080/SW_Server/rest/admin/login";
          alert("uri: "+uri);
          $.ajax({
            async: false,
            url: uri,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            data: { "id":id, "pwd":pwd },
            success: function(data) {
                $('#loginForm').attr('action',data.redirect);
                $('#loginForm').submit();
            },
            error: function(jqHHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("textStatus: "+textStatus+"\nerror: "+errorThrown);      
            }
          });


           // Prevent the form's default submission.
           event.preventDefault();
           // Prevent event from bubbling up DOM tree, prohibiting delegation
           event.stopPropagation();

           //and also    
           return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: Actually, yes I did try that. You'll notice at the top of the code block there that that method is called when the login form's submit button is clicked. Adding the $('#loginForm').submit() in the submit section will result in an infinite loop. Glad I'm not the only one to do that. :)

Comment: hehe ye you are right! didnt thing this throuh.. :)
but why are you setting then the action attr?
did you try encodeURIComponent() and decodeURIComponent()

Comment: I read *somewhere* (can't recall where) that jquery will take the form inputs on a get and add them as query parameters, but that didn't happen. I rewrote the whole method (see above for the new version) and it still behaved the same (went to index.jsp and didn't have query params). Does `window.location.replace`act like a get or a post or something else altogether different? And for the record, its because of stuff like this that I write back-end code for a living. :)